# code for ordered probit model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, fitting

I have a data set with 7 predictor variables and one dependent variable. The dependent variable has 4 categories so it's not binomial.  I need to fit a probit model. I need codes for probit model in R, SPSS or Matlab.

Comment: Please read advice in the Help Center on software-related questions.

Answer (score 4):

These instructions are for R:

For (proportional odds) ordered probit and logit:

```
library(MASS) 
?polr
```

and read the help page that appears.

For (Bayesian) multinomial probit, first install the package MNP then:

```
library(MNP)
?mnp
```

However, this may be overengineered for your purposes.  A simpler package is built in for multinomial logit.

For multinomial logit:

```
library(nnet)
?multinom
```

There is some detailed description [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm) on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.But I have a question. Multinormial probit and ordered logit model.Are they same?

Comment: No. You can (and should) look up the differences.  This will be easier if you spell them the way I did.